# Cant find where [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException] Applies

Tags: java, null

I'm in an intro CS class and I'm writing a program that plays a game. I have the framework classes down but this error occurs when I try to run. It says there is a null point at line 51 in the game method but I can't find where the null point is occurring. Here's the code for the four classes.

```
public class Pog //THIS IS DONE
{
public static void main (String [] Agrs)
{
    PogPlayer human = new PogPlayer( "Human" );
    PogPlayer computer = new PogPlayer( "Computer" );

    PogGame game = new PogGame ( human, computer );
    game.play();

} // method main

} // class Pog

public class PogDice
{
private int die1;   // Stores the value (1-6) of die1.
private int die2;   // Stores the value (1-6) of die2.

private Random rand;

public PogDice()
{
    rand = new Random();

} // default constructor
public int roll()
{
  int total = 0;
  int turnTotal = 0;
  String choice;

  Scanner scan;

  scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {  die1 = rand.nextInt( 5 )+1;
        die2 = rand.nextInt( 5 )+1;
        total = die1+die2;
        System.out.println("Current score is: " + total + "\nRoll again?");
        choice = scan.nextLine();

  } while (choice == "yes" && hasDoubleOne() == false);

  turnTotal = turnTotal + total;
  return turnTotal;

} // method rollDice

public boolean hasDoubleOne()
{
  boolean doubleOne = false;
    if(die1 == 1 && die2 == 1)
     doubleOne = true;
  else
     doubleOne = false;
  return doubleOne;

} // method hasDoubleOne

public String toString()
{
    return (die1 + ", " + die2);

} // method toString

} // class PogDice

 public class PogGame
{
private PogPlayer human;
private PogPlayer computer;

/**
 * PogGame (constructor)
 *
 * @param PogPlayer (human)
 * @param PogPlayer (computer)
 */
public PogGame ( PogPlayer humanArg, PogPlayer computerArg )
{
    PogPlayer human = humanArg;
    PogPlayer comptuer = computerArg;

} // method PogGame (constructor)

public void play()
{
    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to Pog.\n\n This game takes the user "+
                       "and puts them agaisnt the computer\n in a dice-based "+
                       "game. Each player takes turns rolling two dice,\n "+
                       "with their sum being the total points the "+
                       "player gets.\n If you roll two 1s you lose all "+
                       "points that turn.\n You have the option to turn "+
                       "over the dice at any point\n during your turn to "+
                       "keep all of your points.\n First one to 21 wins!.\n");
  human.getCurrent();




} // method play

 } // class pogGame

public class PogPlayer
{
private int current;        // Value of the current roll
private int score;      // Player's point score.

private PogDice dice;   // Player's dice
private String name;        // Player's name.

public final int WINNER = 21;   // number of points required to win

public PogPlayer ( String nameArg )
{
    PogDice dice = new PogDice();
  score = 0;

} // method PogPlayer (constructor)

 public int getCurrent()
 {
  int current;
  current = dice.roll();
  return current;
 } // method getCurrent

public PogDice getDice()
{
  new PogDice();
    return new PogDice();

} // method getDice

public int getScore()
{
    score = current + score;
  return score;

} // method getScore

public boolean hasWon()
{
  boolean win;
    if(score == WINNER)
  {  
     win = true;
  }
  else
     win = false;
  return win;
} // method hasWon

public boolean rollDice()
{
    return false;

} // method rollDice

} // class PogPlayer
```

I'm pretty sure the error is occurring at the human.getCurrent(); line.

Comment: What can cause a NPE at that line?

Comment: Do I get to know what line 51 is?

Comment: Where is your stack trace?

Comment: Line 51 is in the public void play(); at the command human.getCurrent();

Comment: You are shadowing many of your instance variables, like in your `PogGame` constructor. Also don't compare Strings using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String [] Agrs)
{
    PogPlayer human = new PogPlayer( "Human" );
    PogPlayer computer = new PogPlayer( "Computer" );

    PogGame game = new PogGame ( human, computer );
    game.play();

} // method main
```

"human" is a local variable. When you call `human.getCurrent()` in `play`, it's a different human. In particular, a null one that hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't actually setting the `human` and `computer` variables correctly in `PogGame` class, because in the constructor you're creating a new variable, but the instance variable remains null.

```
private PogPlayer human;
private PogPlayer computer;

/**
 * PogGame (constructor)    
 *
 * @param PogPlayer (human)
 * @param PogPlayer (computer)
 */
public PogGame ( PogPlayer humanArg, PogPlayer computerArg )
{
    PogPlayer human = humanArg;  // human is a new variable rather than the human instance variable
    PogPlayer comptuer = computerArg;

}
```

So when you call `human.getCurrent();` here will throw an `NPE` since human didn't initialized.

so change the code to something like:

```
 public PogGame ( PogPlayer humanArg, PogPlayer computerArg )
 {
     human = humanArg;
     comptuer = computerArg;
 }
```

Same thing goes with `dice` in `PogPlayer` constructor, change it to:

```
public PogPlayer(String nameArg) {
    dice = new PogDice();// instead of PogDice dice = new PogDice();
    score = 0;

}
```